# Remove wildcard entries between IP's in file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a very lengthy file(more than 4000 lines generated per day)in the following format.

```
yqiemmtcveihai

test-trans

10.227.30.66

<----------->

14.192.17.143

<----------->

peuddnbtmzdptw

Ttest-trans1

10.227.30.67

<----------->

14.192.17.142

<----------->

cqykfavuxpuqiq

Med

202.21.32.218

<----------->

hziuqbvuncwkie

Myubun

202.21.32.230

<----------->
```

I want to remove the `<----------->` entry only between the IP's. So the result should be in this format.

```
yqiemmtcveihai

test-trans

10.227.30.66

14.192.17.143

<----------->

peuddnbtmzdptw

Ttest-trans1

10.227.30.67

14.192.17.142

<----------->

cqykfavuxpuqiq

Med

202.21.32.218

<----------->

hziuqbvuncwkie

Myubun

202.21.32.230

<----------->
```

Can anyone suggest to me a script, preferably in bash, to achieve this? I was breaking my head, but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to remove the <-----------> entry only between the IP's.

Assuming your problem can be restated as 'I want to remove the lines containing `<----------->`, but only if followed by an IP address', then the examples below may work for you.

Most of these are adaptations of the excellent answers over at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21517723/sed-replace-pattern-only-if-followed-by-empty-line).

#### sed

```
sed -E '$!N;s/<----------->\n(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})/\1/;P;D' input.txt
```

#### awk

```
awk 'NR==1 {l=$0; next}
     /^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/ {
       if(l == "<----------->") { l=$0; next }
     }
     {print l; l=$0}
     END { print l }' input.txt
```

#### perl

```
perl -00 -pe 's/<----------->\n((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/$1/g' input.txt
```

#### python

```
python -c \
  "import re; print re.sub(r'^<----------->\n((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})$',
                           r'\1', open('input.txt').read(), flags=re.M),"
```